# Is the Japanese version of Checkout UI not available?

Tags: square-connect

Is the Japanese version of Checkout UI not available?
Although it is English on the page of https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/square-checkout-overview, the Connect API should also support Japanese, so I would like a Japanese Checkout page?

Answer (score 0):

Square Checkout is not currently available in other languages, but Square is currently working on localization to japanese and other languages.